# How to get href attributefrom html page

Tags: php

I have this html code:

```
<tbody>
<tr  class="">
   <td align="right"  csk="1">1</td>
   <td align="left" ><img src="http://static.spref.com/olympics/images/flags/AFG.png" alt="AFG" title="Afghanistan" height=15 width=22>&nbsp;<a href="/olympics/countries/AFG/">Afghanistan</a></td>
   <td align="right" >1936</td>
   <td align="right" >2016</td>
   <td align="right" >103</td>
   <td align="right" >7</td>
   <td align="right" ></td>
   <td align="right" ></td>
   <td align="right" >2</td>
   <td align="right" >2</td>
   <td align="right" ></td>
   <td align="right" ></td>
   <td align="right" ></td>
   <td align="right" ></td>
   <td align="right" ></td>
   <td align="right" ></td>
   <td align="right" ></td>
   <td align="right" ></td>
</tr>
```

I'd like to get inside an array all the href attributes.
I'm trying to use this php code:

```
<?php

include_once ('/share/Multimedia/simple_html_dom.php');

$url = 'https://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/countries/';
$tagname_tbody = 'tbody';
$tagname_tr = 'td align="left"';


    $olympiad = array();
    $html = file_get_html($url,true);

    foreach($html->find($tagname_tr) as $tag) {
        $olympiad[] = trim($tag->innertext);

    }
```

Indeed if I print olympiad array I get something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => <img src="http://static.spref.com/olympics/images/flags/AFG.png" alt="AFG" title="Afghanistan" height=15 width=22>&nbsp;<a href="/olympics/countries/AFG/">Afghanistan</a>
    [2] => 1936
    [3] => 2016
    [4] => 103
    [5] => 7
    [6] =>
    [7] =>
    [8] => 2
    [9] => 2
    [10] =>
```

Why this behaviour? I'd like to get also the text inside href attribute (in this case Afghanistan), possibly in another array.
I'm not an php code expert so I ask help to you.

Comment: I think rather than getting $tag->innertext, use find in innertext for a tag

Answer (score 0):

You can load the html file like this,this is an exemple you can adapt it:

```
<?php
include_once ('/share/Multimedia/simple_html_dom.php');
$url = 'https://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/countries/';
$tagname_tbody = 'tbody';
$tagname_tr = 'td align="left"';
$olympiad = array();
$html = file_get_html($url,true);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML( $html);
// example 1:
$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('*');
// example 2:
$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('html');
// example 3:
$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body');
// example 4:
$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('table');
// example 5:
$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName('div');
```

I hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all `href` attributes, I think you can add an `a` to  `$tagname_tr = 'td align="left"';`

Then you can loop the result, and get the [href](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#frag_access_attr) and the [innertext](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm).

As an example, the values are stored in 2 arrays and the html is loaded as a string:

```
include_once ('/share/Multimedia/simple_html_dom.php');

$source = <<<SOURCE
<tbody>
<tr  class="">
   <td align="right"  csk="1">1</td>
   <td align="left" ><img src="http://static.spref.com/olympics/images/flags/AFG.png" alt="AFG" title="Afghanistan" height=15 width=22>&nbsp;<a href="/olympics/countries/AFG/">Afghanistan</a></td>
   <td align="right" >1936</td>
   <td align="right" >2016</td>
   <td align="right" >103</td>
   <td align="right" >7</td>
   <td align="right" ></td>
   <td align="right" ></td>
   <td align="right" >2</td>
   <td align="right" >2</td>
   <td align="right" ></td>
   <td align="right" ></td>
   <td align="right" ></td>
   <td align="right" ></td>
   <td align="right" ></td>
   <td align="right" ></td>
   <td align="right" ></td>
   <td align="right" ></td>
</tr>
SOURCE;

$url = 'https://www.sports-reference.com/olympics/countries/';
$tagname_tbody = 'tbody';
$tagname_tr = 'td align="left" a';

$olympiad = array();
$elementText = array();
//$html = file_get_html($url,true);
$html = str_get_html($source);

foreach($html->find($tagname_tr) as $tag) {
    $olympiad[] = $tag->href;
    $elementText[] = $tag->innertext;
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($olympiad);
print_r($elementText);
```

Will result in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => /olympics/countries/AFG/
)
Array
(
    [0] => Afghanistan
)
```